# Need help adding a constructor inside of a function with 2 parameters

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor

Been working through javascript challenges for the past few hours and got stuck on this challenge using the new keyword. I worked out to the best of my ability part 1 and 3 but am terribly confused on part 2. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> **Challenge 1/3**
>
> Create a function PersonConstructor that uses the this
>   keyword to save a single property onto its scope called greet. greet
>   should be a function that logs the string 'hello'.
>
> **Challenge 2/3**
>
> Create a function personFromConstructor that takes as input a name and
>   an age. When called, the function will create person objects using the
>   new keyword instead of the Object.create method.
>
> **Challenge 3/3**
>
> Without editing the code you've already written, add an introduce method to
>   the PersonConstructor function that logs "Hi, my name is [name]".

---

```
*** CHALLENGE 1 of 3 ***/

function PersonConstructor() {
    // add code here
    this.greet = function () {
    console.log('hello');
  }

}


// /********* Uncomment this line to test your work! *********/
var simon = new PersonConstructor;
// simon.greet(); // -> Logs 'hello'



/*** CHALLENGE 2 of 3 ***/

// add code here
function personFromConstructor(name, age) {      


}

var mike = personFromConstructor('Mike', 30);


// /********* Uncomment these lines to test your work! *********/
//console.log(mike.name); // -> Logs 'Mike'
// console.log(mike.age); //-> Logs 30
// mike.greet(); //-> Logs 'hello'



/*** CHALLENGE 3 of 3 ***/
// add code here
PersonConstructor.prototype.introduce = function(){
  console.log('Hi, my name is ' + name)
}


console.log(mike.introduce()); // -> Logs 'Hi, my name is Mike'
```

Comment: Oh, this is actually a different assignment... Re-opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might give you some ideas:

```
function personFromConstructor(name, age) {      
    var person = new PersonConstructor();
    person.name = name;
    person.age = age;
    return person;
}
```

It creates new person object and assigns `name` and `age` properties to it. At the end it returns created person.

Comment: ah brilliant, for some reason i was using this.name=name; instead of declaring person to be referred to as the this keyword. cheers, thx for the help!